# Select only one item in UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've implemented a subclass of UICollectionViewController which is horizontally scrollable and I want it to be able to select ONLY one item at time.

It works fine when I change the selected item on the current screen. However, for example, if I select an item at the very beginning of the collection and then scroll to the right and select another one the first one will still be selected.

Here's the current version of my CollectionView:

```
class GenresCollectionVC: UICollectionViewController {

    var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath?

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource
    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return MockData.instance.genres.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! GenreCollectionViewCell

        cell.genreNameLabel.text = MockData.instance.genres[indexPath.row]
        if selectedIndexPath == indexPath {
            redraw(selectedCell: cell)
        } else {
            redraw(deselectedCell: cell)
        }

        return cell
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? GenreCollectionViewCell else {
            return
        }
        redraw(selectedCell: cell)
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? GenreCollectionViewCell else {
            return
        }
        redraw(deselectedCell: cell)
        selectedIndexPath = nil
    }

    private func redraw(selectedCell cell: GenreCollectionViewCell
        ) {
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = cell.bounds.height / 2
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.violetNeeoColor.cgColor

        cell.genreNameLabel.textColor = UIColor.violetNeeoColor
    }

    private func redraw(deselectedCell cell: GenreCollectionViewCell) {
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0

        cell.genreNameLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your `GenreCollectionViewCell` class, override `isSelected` property, i.e.

```
override var isSelected: Bool{
    willSet{
        super.isSelected = newValue
        if newValue
        {
            self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.height / 2
            self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.violetNeeoColor.cgColor
            self.genreNameLabel.textColor = UIColor.violetNeeoColor
        }
        else
        {
            self.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
            self.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0
            self.genreNameLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        }
    }
}
```

Now you don't need to select/deselect the cell manually in `didSelectItemAt` `delegate` method. `isSelected` property will handle it automatically.

Comment: Cool, it helped me! However could explain why we should call `super.isSelected = newValue`? Deleting this line of code doesn't change anything in my program now

Comment: Doesn't change anything means the program is not working if you delete this line?

Comment: No, everything works fine when I use your code. Even if I delete the line `super.isSelected = newValue` everything still works. So the question is: "Why should I write this line at all and what does it change?"

Comment: You actually don't need that line, I think @PGDev forgot that he was using willSet and not set, super.isSelected = newValue will be called automatically in the implicit `set`

Answer (score 2):

In such scenario saving the `IndexPath` and then using that for the basis of comparison is always the best option for me.

first define your variable:

```
var _selectedIndexPath : IndexPath? = nil
```

Then in your `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath){

            if ((_selectedIndexPath) != nil){

                if indexPath.compare(_selectedIndexPath!) == ComparisonResult.orderedSame {

                    //if the user tap the same cell that was selected previously deselect it.

                    _selectedIndexPath = nil;
                }
                else
                {
\                    // save the currently selected indexPath

                    _selectedIndexPath = indexPath

                }
            }
            else{

                // else, savee the indexpath for future reference if we don't have previous selected cell

                _selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
        }

        // and now only reload only the visible cells

            collectionView.reloadItems(at: collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems)
        }
```

At last check selected cell in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`:

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        // Demo implementation
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)

        if _selectedIndexPath == indexPath{

            //If the cell is selected
            cell.isSelected = true
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        else{
            // If the cell is not selected
            cell.isSelected=false
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray


        }
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: This is the right answer, but the didSelectItem is a little wonky. Here's my gist with a better version: https://gist.github.com/PeeJWeeJ/414897cfeba33a8ea8edb51239a07612

Comment: @GetSwifty Why did you delete your gist, PJ?

Answer (score 1):

Deselect the cell manually after selecting new `indexPath`

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? GenreCollectionViewCell else {
        return
    }
    if selectedIndexPath != indexPath {
        collectionView(collectionView, didDeselectItemAt: selectedIndexPath)
     }
    redraw(selectedCell: cell)
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
}
```

Apparently deselect delegate method is called every second tap on a cell.

Answer (score 1):

```
private var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath? = nil

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "tagcell", for: indexPath) as! TagCell
        cell.title = items[indexPath.item]
        cell.isSelected = selectedIndexPath == indexPath
        return cell
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        if selectedIndexPath != nil {
            if indexPath != selectedIndexPath {
                selectedIndexPath = indexPath
            }
        } else {
            selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        }

        collectionView.reloadItems(at: collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems)
    }
```